# How do I access BuildContext outside of a stateful or stateless widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I created a class that extends the AppBar class in Flutter so I can reuse it whenever I need it.
My problem is how do I access the Stateful/Stateless widget build context?

```
class AppBarLayout extends AppBar {

  static final AppController _appController = new AppController();

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey;
  final String appBarTitle;

  AppBarLayout(this.appBarTitle,this._scaffoldKey): super(
    title: Text(appBarTitle),
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
        iconSize: 28,
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.white),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () => _appController.signOut().then((_) {
            _appController.navigateTo(context, new GoogleSignView());
          }),
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          ),
      ],
  );
}
```

Comment: You would need to pass the context in the constructor, the same as you are passing appBarTitle

Comment: @Hosar I did that using this code: `static BuildContext _context = HomeState().context;` but when I pass _context in the constructor and run the app I get the error: `Reading static variable '_context@25445118' during its initialization`

Comment: Where are you using the AppBarLayout, in a Scaffold ?

Comment: @Hosar yes, my intention was making it reusable for all screens. With only the title being the property that needs changing, and of course the scaffold key for some drawer operations

Comment: Why do you need to get the context of another widget? `AppBar` is a widget itself, so it has it's own `context` field.

Comment: @Abion47 I need the context for the Navigator class, I think I need the scaffold context for it and not the appbar context?

Comment: As long as the `Navigator` in question is an ancestor of both the `Scaffold` and the `AppBar` (which I assume it would be, seeing as the `Scaffold` is the direct parent of the `AppBar`, then it doesn't matter. The context would get the right `Navigator` no matter which context you chose.

Comment: The reason it works is because `Navigator.of` wraps a call to [`BuildContext.ancestorStateOfType`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/ancestorStateOfType.html) which gets you the instance of the nearest widget state of a particular `StatefulWidget` (in this case `NavigatorState`) from the current widget's ancestors. Since there's an implicit `Navigator` as part of the `MaterialApp` that is an ancestor of both the scaffold and the app bar, you could call `Navigator.of` using either of those widget's contexts and it will find the same one.

Comment: And yes, using the `Navigator`'s static methods where you pass in the context as a parameter is the same thing - it just calls `Navigator.of` for you. (e.g. Doing `Navigator.pop(context);` is semantically identical to calling `Navigator.of(context).pop();`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to wrap your **Scaffold** in a Staless or Stateful widget, so you can get the context, e.g.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBarLayout(GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'someLabel'), appBarTitle: 'The Title', context: context,),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class AppBarLayout extends AppBar {

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey;
  final String appBarTitle;
  final BuildContext context;

  AppBarLayout(this._scaffoldKey, {this.appBarTitle, this.context}): super(
    title: Text(appBarTitle),
      leading: IconButton(
        onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
        iconSize: 28,
        icon: Icon(Icons.menu,color: Colors.white),
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('Button pressed');
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.account_box),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          ),
      ],
  );
}
```

Here I'm using a very similar Widget of what you have.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you find yourself passing around global keys like this just to get access to other widgets' fields and functions, it's a sign that you need to rethink your approach.

Comment: What about using Builder class? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html